# Convolution of multiple exponential distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to figure out the derivation presented on page 442 of [this paper](http://web.eve.ucdavis.edu/pbg298/pdfs/Genetics_1983-Tajima.pdf).

> Given a probability distribution 
>   $$f_n(t) \frac{\binom{n+1}{2}}{2N}\exp{\left(-\frac{t\binom{n+1}{2}}{2N}\right)}$$
>   which is (obviously) exponentially distributed with parameters $\lambda=\frac{\binom{n+1}{2}}{2N}$, show that the expected value ($E$) and variance ($V$) of the convolution of $f_{n-1}(t), f_{n-2}(t),...,f_m(t)$ is:
>   $$E(t) = 2N \sum_{i=m+1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\binom{i}{2}}} = 4N\left(\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
>   $$
> V(t) = 4N^2\sum_{i=m+1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\binom{i}{2}^2}}
> $$

I feel like I should be able to figure this out, but I can't seem to get on the right track. If anyone has any insight or references I'd be very appreciative!

Comment: You need a minus sign in the definition of the exponential distribution.

Comment: sorry, yes, this is fixed

Comment: The convolution of pdfs corresponds to the addition of random variables $X_n$ (independence assumed...) having these pdfs ; thus your first formula is a consequence of the linearity of mathematical expectation under the form $E(\sum X_n)=\sum E(X_n)$ ; the same for variances (it is where independence has to be assumed)

Comment: Oh, wow, of course that's what it is... What a dumb question in hindsight. Thank you JeanMarie. Do you know the derivation of the $\sum_{i=m+1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\binom{i}{2}}} = 2(\frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: Re the query in your last comment, use $$\frac1{{i\choose2}}=\frac2{i(i-1)}=\frac2{i-1}-\frac2i.$$

Comment: Wow, thank you all. Very helpful.